# Form onChange working, however fails to work when I change it to onSubmit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been stuck trying to figure this out for ages. For some reason when the inputs onSubmit is set to onChange, it fires correctly. However I need it to be onSubmit, as I don't want it firing on every change. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and why the onSubmit isn't working for the input. I'm trying to set the state and update the URL query for something like:

"website.com/browse?country={text from input}"

```
const [countryQuery, setCountryQuery] = useQueryState("country", "")

const handleSubmitCountry = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setCountryQuery()
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmitCountry}>
    <input 
        placeholder={countryQuery}
        type="text" 
        className={styles.searchInput}
        onSubmit={e => setCountryQuery(e.target.value)} 
    />      
</form>
```

Comment: Change this ```onSubmit={e => setCountryQuery(e.target.value)}``` by ```onChange={e => setCountryQuery(e.target.value)}```

Comment: so you have a input button inside form, and i think you will have a submit button once you click the submit button only the handleSubmitCountry should trigger, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I don't think **input** has an onSubmit prop. Maybe using **onBlur** will fix your issue.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks. But how do I get the value of the type input from within handleSubmitCountry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the input's value from the form's `onSubmit` event in the handler using the input's name.

Don't attach any event handlers to the input element in order to leave it as an uncontrolled input, add a button/input to trigger the form `onSubmit` handler.

```
const handleSubmitCountry = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const countryQuery = e.target.countryQuery.value;
  // use countryQuery now
  countryQuery && alert(`Submitted Country Query: ${countryQuery}`);
};

...
<form onSubmit={handleSubmitCountry}>
  <input name="countryQuery" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[image: Edit intelligent-cloud-6e0y9]